# Let reader know that writer finished writing, and wait for reader to finish reading

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, reader, writer

I've got the following reader-writer scenario:

1. A writer fires a reader.
2. The reader spins infinitely, and starts reading from a shared buffer once it's written into.
3. A writer starts writing to the shared buffer
4. The writer waits for the reader to finish reading.
5. program ends.

Pseudo code - please assume everything is thread safe:

```
// shared buffer
var buffer = new [3];

// 1. fire a thread, pass it a function named read
thread reader = new thread(read);

// 2. write some text to a shared buffer
var source = new [] {"line 1", "line 2", "line 3"};
for (int i = 0; ++i; i< source.length) {
   buffer[i] = source[i];
}

// 3. wait for reader to finish consuming the buffer
reader.join();


// 4. reader function
function void read() {
    while (true) {
        while (!buffer.empty()) {
           for (int i = 0; ++i; i< buffer.length) {
              print(buffer[i]);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

My question: How to make the reader get out of its infinite loop?

I know it's a classic problem, but couldn't find a resource that deals with it. All I've seen deals with different kinds of locks, which is not the thing I'm interested in (as said - please assume everything is thread safe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shared flag, `finished`.

When the writer finishes writing its content, it sets the flag, `finished = true`.

Instead of letting the reader loop forever with `while (true)`, terminate when the flag is set, `while (!finished)`.

Comment: Note that in production code you would want to use a condition variable or some other kind of formal thread-signaling mechanism, rather than polling a shared boolean variable, because polling loops either waste too many CPU cycles (if they are spinloops) or introduce unnecessary latency (if they sleep between polls to try to avoid wasting CPU).

Comment: 1. Writer fires reader 
2. Reader gets cpu time, finish evaluating `!buffer.empty()'
3. Writer gets back cpu time, writes, sets flag 
4. Reader gets cpu time 
5. Reader exits without reading

Comment: @odyssey Check the buffer again after the loop terminates. If not empty, process its content.